# Why is this question on blood supply in tendon downvoted?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, down-votes

Because of one downvote, the question got removed after 30 days. I reposted it and it got downvoted then removed again after 30 after days. The mods don't want me to repost the question as such for a third time, because it has already been removed twice. Therefore I'd like to know how I can improve the question. Thanks!

---

The question's title was: [Does any tendon in humans receive a high amount of blood supply? Or is the property of not receiving a large blood supply a constant across tendons?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/101332/630)

The question's body was:

> I read on https://www.physiocomestoyou.co.uk/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-tendons/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190528002217/https://www.physiocomestoyou.co.uk/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-tendons/)):
>
> [Tendons] do not have a large blood supply.
>
> Does any tendon in the human body receive a high amount of blood supply? E.g., one could define high as significantly higher than the median observed blood supplies across tendons. Or is the property of not receiving a large blood supply a constant across tendons in the human body?
>
> ---
>
> [Mike Serfas](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/57271/mike-serfas) pointed me to [physio-pedia's page on tendon anatomy](https://www.physio-pedia.com/Tendon_Anatomy) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201211040944/https://www.physio-pedia.com/Tendon_Anatomy)), which  mentions blood supply variations within a tendon:
>
> > The point at which the tendon forms attachment to the muscle is also known as the musculotendinous junction (MTJ) and the point at which it attaches to the bone is known as the osteotendinous junction (OTJ). Vascularity of a tendon is very important when considering the healing process. Blood supply from tendons can be split into two sources; the intrinsic and the extrinsic. The intrinsic sources are at the MTJ and the OTJ, while the extrinsic are at through the paratenon or the synovial sheath.The blood supply to specific areas are supplied by different sources. The intrinsic at the MTJ has been documented to extend into 1/3 of the tendon whereas the bloody supply originating from the OTJ is more avascular and is limited to the insertional point. This leave the extrinsic source to supply the mid portion of the tendon. Studies have shown that tendons have significantly reduced vascularity around bony pulleys.
>
> I'd be interested to know how much blood supply variation there is *between* tendons.

Comment: I think that you deserve an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was the downvoter the previous time your question was posted. I downvoted because it was posted in the exact same format (copy and paste) to the previous versions of the question that were removed for having non-positive score.

I have had previous public interactions with you on meta talking about the problem of reposting dead questions without any efforts to update them. Based on the way that discussion went, I figured it best at that time to just add my opinion with a downvote rather than taking mod action, and did not particularly want to start another argument that would not likely leave either of us more satisfied than we were before.

I think probably the reason your question was originally not received well is that it's asking for quantitative outliers/exceptions to a qualitative description, and then adds a meaningless add-on question that's either trivially false or true only by someone's definition. Like if someone wrote "bananas are larger than raspberries" and you asked "are there any bananas smaller than raspberries? If not, are all bananas the same size?" I think questions posted that way make it sound mostly like you haven't understood what was being said in the original statement you read, and tend to invite bickering about the answer if it's not what OP wanted/expected.

I feel like Mike Serfas gave you a great avenue towards improving your question, like asking "are certain tendons considered 'more vascularized' than others" or "is there any tendon that receives an uncharacteristic/unusual amount of 'intrinsic' blood supply". Instead you've just attached the quote to your question without any visible effort to understand and apply what was said to your original question.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple (and is the same as in the mail the mod team has already sent to you): You asked and deleted this question multiple time (about 13x if my count is right), which is not seen as acceptable here.

To quote the text you already got:

> This is regarded as "noise" on Biology Stack Exchange. If your
> question was closed as unanswerable or did not attract responses, then
> the first thing to do is to improve the question; some guidance for
> this is given here. Low-quality or unanswerable questions will
> typically be closed, but can be re-opened if improved or clarified (as
> appropriate).
>
> To re-iterate; do not keep re-asking the same question.

I hope this clears the question.

Comment: That doesn't clear the question at my meta question at all. My meta question is: "Because of one downvote, the question about tendons got removed. Therefore I'd like to know how I can improve the question." I did repost the latest version of the question twice 
because each time one or two downvotes caused it to be removed 30 days after posting. I had already explained in my reply to the mod team by the way, and mentioned this is the reason why I created this meta question: to understand the one or two downvotes on my tendon question. And ironically you're now downvoting my meta question...